# How do I make Ubuntu look "Classic?"

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)
>   [Can a Gnome2 like interface be built upon the new Gnome3 code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68495/can-a-gnome2-like-interface-be-built-upon-the-new-gnome3-code)

How do I make an Ubuntu 11.10 setup running XFCE, or maybe GNOME 3 classic mode look and behave exactly like the classic Ubuntu setup of Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install Gnome Panel:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

It's a little different than the Gnome Panel of 10.10 but it looks like.

Comment: How do I customize Gnome-panel?

Answer (score 1):

well, you may choose to install xubuntu: http://www.xubuntu.org/ or if you have ubuntu with unity already installed, you can install the xfce desktop by:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

OR

you install gnome 3 by:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

When installed, you may choose it in the login screen (gnome classic is what you mean). Thats it.

Comment: Word of warning - installing `xubuntu-desktop` over existing Ubuntu installation may break other environments.
You can install `xfce4` for a minimal XFCE desktop, to just try things out.
Once you make up your mind, you can set desktop of your choice as default - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-lightdm-when-using-auto-logins

Comment: Why would xubuntu-desktop break anything? There is a conflict between the notification system of ubuntu-desktop and xubuntu-desktop, but that'll be pulled in with Xfce as well.

Comment: jnv: Thx for your comment i have included your recommendation.